# Cant find SQL predefined prereqs ( .PRQ's )

Tags: c#, wpf, installshield

I am trying to create a setup for WPF application using installshield 2010.

Under prerequisites tab I am adding sqlserver msi but after adding it.
I am unable to see the sql server predefined prereqs ( .PRQ's ) in the list of installshield predefined prereqs ( .PRQ's ) so that i can check it and move further with the setup craetion process.

Help Highly Appreciated.

Comment: Could you clarify that this prq is correct and wasn't corrupted?